# Why evaluatePolicy fails only once if TouchID is turn off for iPhone Unlock

Tags: ios, swift, touch-id

I want to use TouchID in my app and I've found some weird behaviour. So in general when TouchID alert is shown it and user try to authenticate with fingerprint canEvaluatePolicy will fail only after 3 attempts but if user go to Settings>Touch ID & Passcode and turn off "use touch id for: iPhone Unlock" canEvaluatePolicy will fail after first attempt with error message "Biometry is disabled for unlock.". Does anyone know is it a bug or it is by design.
Also looks like it happens only on iOS 11.

Here is code that i use for TouchID configuration

```
    var error: NSError?
    context.localizedFallbackTitle = "fallback title"

    if context.canEvaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, error: &error) {
        context.evaluatePolicy(.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: reason) { success, authenticationError in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if success {
                    // success case
                }
                else {
                    // error handling
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        // error handling
    }
```

Comment: Seems to be correct, it's explained in the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/lacontext/1514149-canevaluatepolicy?language=objc

Comment: @rckoenes you talking about this line "a policy that requires biometrics would require that Touch ID or Face ID has not been previously disabled." ?